# BRST structure functions in gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, hamiltonian-formalism, brst, adm-formalism

In the *classical* Hamiltonian BRST formalism, there arise structure functions $\Omega^{\beta_1...\beta_n}_{\alpha_1...\alpha_{n+1}}$ ($n\geq0$) --- see https://inspirehep.net/literature/221897 for example. These are such that the BRST charge
$$
\Omega=\sum_{n\geq0}c^{\alpha_1}...c^{\alpha_{n+1}}b_{\beta_1}...b_{\beta_n}\Omega^{\beta_1...\beta_n}_{\alpha_1...\alpha_{n+1}}
$$
is real (we assume $c$ and $b$ are real and Grassmann valued) *and* $\{\Omega,\Omega\}_{\text{PB}}=0$ ($\{,\}_{\text{PB}}$ being the Poisson bracket). The zero'th order structure functions, $\Omega_{\alpha}$,
are the constraints themselves. The higher-order structure functions can be solved for recursively -- starting with $\Omega_{\alpha}$ -- using the properties of $\Omega$ stated above and the constraint algebra. The 'rank' of the theory is defined as the order of the highest non-vanishing structure function (the order of a structure function is simply the number of upper indices it has).

My question is, for pure 3+1 dimensional (Einstein) gravity, what is the rank of the theory, and furthermore, has anyone worked out all the structure functions explicitly?

Comment: This paper https://doi.org/10.1143/PTP.60.272 appears to be related (see eq. (4.9))

Comment: although, said paper uses the Lagrangian formalism to derive the BRST charge and, in particular, their $\Omega_\alpha$ doesn't coincide with the constraints

Comment: Section 4.2 of [arXiv:1206.4823](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4823) states, "Although as we will see, ADM gravity has a soft first class constraint algebra, it is still of rank one, meaning that it does not possess terms with two or more ghost momenta."

Comment: @AlexNelson Very interesting. They go further and give the BRST charge in eq. (43) but I've yet to check this is correct

Comment: @AlexNelson Just out of curiosity: did you use chatgpt to help find that paper?

Comment: the thought never occurred to me; when I tried using ChatGPT for finite group theory references, it just produced fictitious "references" which do not exist, and that steered me away from ChatGPT. (And they all lived happily ever after.)

Comment: @AlexNelson Do you know if any textbooks cover this phenomenon? I don't seem to be able to verify their result.

Comment: What phenomenon? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: The earliest instance of writing down the BRST charge for the ADM formalism that I am aware of, is in Guven and Ryan's "Functional integrals and canonical quantum gravity" (1991) [doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.45.3559](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.45.3559), see section IV.D; it seems self-contained.

Comment: I want to add a couple of references the OP might or might not find useful/ interesting. The quantization of gauge theories via constraints and BRST is very well treated in "Quantization of Gauge Systems, Henneaux and Teitelboim". The best book about quantization of gravity via constraints is for sure "Modern Canonical Quantum General Relativity, Thiemann". That is THE book on the subject but it's a bit heavy in the math side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a general system and assume it is rank one. Then $\{\Omega,\Omega\}=0$ is equivalent to \begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\{\Omega_{\alpha_1},\Omega^{\beta_1}_{\alpha_2\alpha_3}\}+\Omega^{\beta}_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}\Omega_{\beta\alpha_3}^{\beta_1}+\text{cyclic permutations of ($\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$)}&=0  \tag{1}  \\
\{\Omega^{\beta_1}_{[\alpha_1\alpha_2},\Omega^{\beta_2}_{\alpha_3\alpha_4]}\}&=0  \tag{2} 
\end{align}
where $[\alpha_1...\alpha_n]$ denotes complete anti-symmetrisation of the indices, $\{,\}$ is the Poisson bracket and
$$
\{\Omega_{\alpha_1},\Omega_{\alpha_2}\}=-2\Omega^{\beta}_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}\Omega_\beta
$$
(1) is actually equivalent to the Jacobi identity:
$$\{\Omega_{\alpha_1},\{\Omega_{\alpha_2},\Omega_{\alpha_3}\}\}+\text{cyclic permutations of ($\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$)}=0$$
so is always satisfied. A system is therefore of rank one iff (2) holds.

In gravity, $\Omega^{\beta}_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}$ is a function of the metric only (and not the conjugate momenta); so Poisson brackets in (2) vanish and the system is rank one.

See https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.35.3878 for discussion of certain rank one systems.